# How to avoid MQRC2033 NO_MSG_AVAILABLE

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a simple program to process messages from a queue.
My intention is to process all available messages in queue and still listen to queue for incoming messages.

I have written the processing part inside a infinite loop as i want it to listen to queue always and process messages.

Once after processing all messages again it tries to get a message(as it is inside a infinite loop) from the queue and there

is no messages it throws MQRC 2033 NO_MSG_AVAILABLE exception(infact it is correct) and my program exits.

Can someone give an idea to continously listen to this queue and avoid this exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you execute the `MQGET` API call, there is an option to have the program wait for messages.  You can specify a wait time (in milliseconds) or specify to wait forever.  Just make sure that if you have the app wait for more than a few seconds, also specify 'Fail if Quiescing'.  This allows the queue manager to be stopped cleanly.  Without 'Fail if Quiescing' the administrator will need to issue a preemptive shutdown which can cause problems.

There is a section specifically for this question in the Programmer's Guide in the [Waiting for Messages](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg12760_.htm) chapter.  Depending on the language you are writing in ,the actual value to specify is in the [Programmer's Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzak.doc/fr10120_.htm), the [Using Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/uj10120_.htm) manual or the [Using .Net](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un10120_.htm) manual.  Each of these will be visible in the navigation panel when you click the link above.

Comment: Thanks Rob.. I specified MQWI_UNLIMITED in my get option.. It worked as expected.Thank you so much.